# SQL Query to Compare two columns in database table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a view to show name, and wrong_zipcode for the customer that has an incorrect zipcode in the customers table below, assume we have another table call usstates that has the correct zipcodes.

My code looks this way:
create view test as select name, zipcode from Customer c,usstates u where c.zipcode not in (select zipcode from usstates);

[Customer table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xj8z.jpg)

[usstates table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ING4X.jpg)

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: yes, i did, i will upload my code now. its not working, getting a wrong answer

Comment: create view test as select name, zipcode from Customer c,usstates u where c.zipcode not in (select zipcode from usstates);

Comment: For next time, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question right, you got two tables. One with customer information and one with zip codes and you want to find all rows in the customer table where the zip code entered does not exist in the zip code table?

In that case you could use something like this.

```
SELECT NAME, ZIPCODE from Customers where not exists (SELECT TOP 1 ZIPCODE from MyZipCodeTable where Customers.ZIPCODE = MyZipCodeTable.ZIPCODE)
```

Comment: yes, the zipcode in the usstates table is right, so i want to find the rows in the customer table where zipcode is wrong, comparing both tables

Comment: Then you can use this code, you will get all rows where the zip code does not exist in the MyZipCodeTable

Comment: i got an empty set from your above query

Comment: Did you rename the table names and column names according to your table and column names? (if not you should get some error message, unless you swallow the exception in some code somewhere)

Comment: Yes i did rename the table and column, at first i got an "unexpected top identifier" error. Then i removed top and query ran successfully, but after i select * from the table, i got no result.

Comment: are you sure you actually got some with wrong zip code?

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about that? We join the two tables with the zipcode and we eliminate the rows where the state doesn't match.

```
CREATE VIEW customers_with_wrong_zipcode AS
  SELECT customers.customer_id, customers.zipcode AS wrong_zipcode, customers.state
  FROM customers
  INNER JOIN us_states ON us_states.zipcode = customers.zipcode
  WHERE us_states.state <> customers.state;
```

Comment: Glad to hear that @masquellett! Can you accept my answer then? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`

```
Select *
From customers c
Where not exists
(select 1 from usstates where zipcode = c.zipcode);
```